# Using native objects in C++/CLI code

Tags: c++-cli

This is the first time I ever came across C++/CLI implementation. So, I have a managed **C++/CLI class** which is implementing the events thrown by a managed API. I want to pass some attributes collected over here as a consequence of events to some native classes.
My question is can I choose native objects to be data member of this C++/CLI class?

Comment: Purged references to C# and C++, the divide is managed and native, both in C++/CLI.

Comment: @Deduplicator I didn't get you.Could you please elaborate on this.

Comment: Just use a pointer to the native object, they can't get screwed up when the garbage collector moves the managed object when it compacts the heap.  Don't forget to add a destructor and finalizer to the class, you need to release them again.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. Why finalizer is needed. Do I need to take care of unmanaged resources also?

Comment: Of course you need to take care of them, nobody else does. Boilerplate is to allocate them in the constructor and destroy them again in the destructor.  Just like you do in a C++ program.  The finalizer ensures that this happens even if the C# programmer forgets to call Dispose().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not. Hybrid types are not allowed. The only workaround is to have a pointer to an unmanaged object inside a managed one. That's it as far as I know.